# Is it possible to filter out some elements on Laravel's backpack reorder?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm using Backpack 3.4 on one of my websites, and as I'm reordering some elements, I'd like to know if it's possible not to display some elements (they have a database field "displayed" set to 0), in order to make this view easier to manage ?

I've seen no info on [the official documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.4/crud-operation-reorder).

Thanks for everything, and have a nice year !

Answer (score 1):

In Backpack 3.4, you should be able to change what entries get shown in the Reorder operation by overwriting the `reorder()` method in your controller:

```php
    /**
     *  Reorder the items in the database using the Nested Set pattern.
     *
     *  Database columns needed: id, parent_id, lft, rgt, depth, name/title
     *
     *  @return Response
     */
    public function reorder()
    {
        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('reorder');

        if (! $this->crud->isReorderEnabled()) {
            abort(403, 'Reorder is disabled.');
        }

        // get all results for that entity
        $this->crud->addClause('where', 'displayed', 0);

        $this->data['entries'] = $this->crud->getEntries();
        $this->data['crud'] = $this->crud;
        $this->data['title'] = $this->crud->getTitle() ?? trans('backpack::crud.reorder').' '.$this->crud->entity_name;

        // load the view from /resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/ if it exists, otherwise load the one in the package
        return view($this->crud->getReorderView(), $this->data);
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it this evening !